# problem with find (shell script)

Tags: shell-script, find

I want the files of a given directory and use the following script:

```
echo "give name of directory: "
read directory
if  [ -d "$directory"   ]
then 
echo "thanks again"
else exit
fi
find  /-type f $directory
```

Unfortunately this does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `find` command is wrongly written:

```
find  /-type f $directory
```

Should be:

```
find "$directory" -type f
```

Note that the `find` command is recursive. If you are only interested in files in the exactly given directory use:

```
find "$directory" -maxdepth 1 -type f
```

And finally to add a little simpler version:

```
echo "give name of directory: "
read directory
if  [ -d "$directory" ]
then 
    echo "thanks again"
    find  "$directory" -maxdepth 1 -type f
fi
```

Comment: i was trying with an emty directory xD

Answer (score 1):

`find $directory -type f`

that will find all the files in that directory including any sub directories

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing here, but this might be what you want:

```
echo "give name of directory: " 
read directory 
if [ -d "$directory" ]
then 
    echo "thanks again" 
else 
    exit 
fi 
find $directory -type f
```

You had `find` looking in /, the root directory.